# How to insert nodes at a linked list in order

Tags: java, node.js, insert, linked-list

Today is my Third Year on learning computer programming in class. I am pleased to say that throughout the months I've been able to attain good grades. I wouldn't have done it without the help from this site by looking at the other questions and adapting the similar answers to use them to help me out on assignments and diagnostic tests.

Now I have another problem, and I feel like it's a huge one. Today I've been given an assignment by another professor(due in 2 weeks time) that involve regarding employees, double linked lists, and testing, and this time we are allowed to use some shortcuts, but because most of the methods were written already, we are assumed to use those instead and since all of them are incomplete, we're supposed finish them.

I came across a problem regarding the method *addInOrder*. The Algorithm is designed to take a object and insert it inside as another node. Although I have rewrote it so that it can add the node at the end(in case the object is larger than the others, or if the list itself is empty), **I have no way on how to add certain conditions so that it can be added in the middle/beginning of the list**.

I have debugged it and I found out that it has something to do with what I wrote down in the method addInOrder, as I have tested the other methods that were used for the test and they did work with no errors.

How do I rewrite the method to include those sort of conditions?

OS: Windows 7 Workbench: Eclipse

the class has only 2 nodes: head, tail. It also uses an imported class known as Employee(which I already finished with no errors).

```
public void addInOrder(Employee employee) {
    Node Previous = null;
    Node position = head;
    while(position != null){
        if(position.getEmployee().compareTo(employee) > 0){
            this.setHead(new Node(employee,position.getPrevious(), position));
            return;
        }
        Previous = position;
        position = position.getNext();
    }
    if(isEmpty() == true || head == null || Previous.getNext() == null)
        this.add(employee);


}
```

EDIT: This is actually the AddInOrder method.

```
    public void testAddInOrder() {
    EmployeeList list = new EmployeeList();
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("d", 12.5));
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("e", 13.5));
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("a", 12.5));
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("g", 13.5));
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("c", 13));
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("a", 12.5));
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("b", 13.5));
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("d", 12.8));
    list.addInOrder(new Employee("b", 13));
    //A12.5 B13 B13 B13.5 C13 D12.5 D12.8 E13.5 G13.5
    assertEquals("a",list.get(0).getName());
    assertEquals("a",list.get(1).getName());
    assertEquals("b",list.get(2).getName());
    assertEquals("b",list.get(3).getName());
    assertEquals("c",list.get(4).getName());
    assertEquals("d",list.get(5).getName());
    assertEquals("d",list.get(6).getName());
    assertEquals("e",list.get(7).getName());
    assertEquals("g",list.get(8).getName());
    assertEquals(12.5, list.get(0).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
    assertEquals(12.5, list.get(1).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
    assertEquals(13, list.get(2).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
    assertEquals(13.5, list.get(3).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
    assertEquals(13, list.get(4).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
    assertEquals(12.5, list.get(5).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
    assertEquals(12.8, list.get(6).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
    assertEquals(13.5, list.get(7).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
    assertEquals(13.5, list.get(8).getSalaryRate(), 0.01);
}
```

this is the test to accompany it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void addInOrder(Employee employee){

if (head==null){//if your list is empty just insert it in the beginning
head=new Node(employee);
return;
}//end if(head==null)


if (head.getNext()==null)//if we have one node only{
if(position.getEmployee().compareTo(employee) > 0){//if it should be replaced than put it in the beginning
Node node=new Node(employee);
node.setNext(head);
head=node;
node.getNext().setPrevious(node);
return;
    }
else{
//add it to the end,i am assuming you know how to do that,if not than comment on my answer.
return;
       }
}
else{
Node position=head;
while(position!=null){
if(position.getEmployee().compareTo(employee) > 0){
Node node=new Node(employee);           //you should add the node before position
node.setNext(position);                 //so set the node's next to position
node.setPrevious(position.getPrevious());//set the node's previous to position's previous
position.getPrevious.setNext(node);      //set the next of position's previous to node
return;//and exit
           }
position=position.getNext();//else continue looping through the list
      }
//if we looped through the whole array and we haven't inserted the node so we didn't              exit the method,than add it to the end.
 Node n=new Node(employee);

 position.setNext(new Node(n);
 n.setPrevious(position);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to think about writing this: Suppose you have a list that's in order. If you know that to be true, you can easily add an item in order by advancing through the list until the item to insert is greater than the previous item and less than or equal to the next item. At that point, simply point the previous to the to_insert and point the to_insert to the next and you're good. If you do this, your list stays in order. 
To deal with the initial insert, you could simply take that case first, outside the loop: if the item to insert sorts before the first item, insert it before the first item and return.

You also know that a list with no items is in order, so you can always start with a list that's in sorted order. So this shouldn't be hard to do - just write the method I've described above. 
Since this is a homework assignment, I'm not going to comment on your code, but if you ask specific questions about it I might offer a hint.

Answer (score 0):

The way I can think of `---->` In insert add statement that traverse through the list and find the most optimal position . Something like

1. `while (tempptr->next != NULL && tempptr->data >= nodelist->data )`
2. `if true----> insert in that position`